# Refresh checkout in woocommerce_after_checkout_validation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

A client is asking to allow users to register during checkout. The problem is there are some logic about memberships so registering can alter the final price and I can't use the standard Woocommerce way.

So i wrote a couple of validations. First i check if everything is in order, if it is a second validation actually creates the customer account, set all meta fields, login the customer.

Now what I need is to fully realod the checkout page and output a notice telling the customer to press the checkout button again.

I'm using woocommerce_after_checkout_validation but I can't make it work.
I tried a wp_redirect and outputting an ugly  in the error notice.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You can add some marker variable to GET or SESSION and render page based on this after redirect, is not it?

Comment: @shvv I ended up using Woocommerce JS hooks. The solution is not perfect but it should be the right way. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Javascript hooks to fire an event after the validation. The error checking is pretty bad, in my case it works but it should be more general.

```
  var error_text = jQuery(".woocommerce-error").find("li").first().text();
  if (
    error_text.trim() ==
    "register_success"
  ) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      location.reload();
    }, 1500);
  }
});
```